# How to deploy React to Azure Web App using the Azure App Service plugin in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service

I tried following the many existing questions and blogs online but I couldn't get it to work, I have created a simple React app with this setup:

[image]

It run fine locally.  I also ran "npm run build".  I also added a web.config to my public folder, which got copied to my build folder with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<configuration>    
    <system.webServer>    
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
        <rewrite>    
            <rules>    
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">    
                    <match url=".*" />    
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">    
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />    
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />    
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />    
                    </conditions>    
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />    
                </rule>    
            </rules>    
        </rewrite>    
    </system.webServer>    
</configuration>
```

My public folder look like this:

[image]

I create my Azure Web App online fine and I was able to deploy to it but I browse to it I get this error:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

What error do I have?

Comment: Did you find any help from Kudu Logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
> occurred.

This error may occur if application is not deployed properly or dependencies are not  loaded.

**Steps to deploy React to Azure Web App :**

- Open your Project in VS Code
- Go to Extensions. Search for Azure App Service and click on Install.
  [image]
- Go to Azure App Service. Sign in to your Azure Account.
- Click on Deploy to Web App.
- Select your Subscription. Select your App Service.
- Now you should be able to deploy your react app to Azure App Service

[image]

[image]